# nginx: [emerg] bind() to ip:3000 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

I want running my server(nodejs) without server name. Only running on my ip address. Here is my config file:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/server.com.conf

```
server {
    listen xx.xx.xx.xx:3000 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000";
    }
}
```

When I restart nginx and see status I get this error:

nginx: [emerg] bind() to ip:3000 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Where is my wrong? Please help me

Comment: You can't bind to an IP address not assigned to your computer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how can I fix that? this is IP of my server

Comment: Why have you tried to bind to that address? Why have you tried to bind to port 3000?

Comment: I want access my server by that address. And my node server running on port 3000

Comment: You already have the node server running on that address! You can't run anything else on it.

Answer (score 1):

If your nodejs is running in different server as the `NGINX`, you can define `upstream` in the nginx config. Leave the `listen` parameter as port number only.

Example:

```
upstream yournodejsserver {
     server xx.xx.xx.xx:3000;
}

server {
    listen 3000;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://yournodejsserver;
    }
}
```

Ref:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen